# UItableview screen shot

Tags: ios

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.reportList.frame.size);
CGRect tableViewFrame = self.reportList.frame;
self.reportList.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.reportList.frame.size.width, self.reportList.contentSize.height);
[self.reportList.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *attachmentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
self.reportList.frame = tableViewFrame;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

By using above code i am getting screenshot of tableview ,my problem is screen shot of tableview is having cell accessory type of discloser indicator but i don't need that cell type .Is any way to remove that accessory type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the accessory indicator to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` before taking screenshot and then set it back to `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`.

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: Thanks @matheszabi. +1 to you too, coz yours is also correct. You just missed the point that it can be put back after taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

you can set the cell type to None, on that case you will not have, but not only at screenshoot, but in app either